# Font property not working on QListView item sub-control

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I can't get the font property to work on a QListView item sub-control with the following code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListView>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

// Herited model with all items flagged as disabled except the first one
class Model : public QFileSystemModel
{
    public:
        Model() : QFileSystemModel() { }
        Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
        {
            if(index.row() > 0)
                return Qt::NoItemFlags;
            else
                return QFileSystemModel::flags(index);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListView v;
    Model* m = new Model;
    m->setRootPath("/");
    v.setModel(m);
    v.setRootIndex(m->index("/"));

    // STYLE
    QString style = "";

    style += "QListView { ";
    style += "background: lightgrey;";
    style += "}";

    style += "QListView::item { ";
    style += "font: bold italic large \"Arial\";"; // Font doesn't work
    style += "height: 40px;"; // Height works
    style += "}";

    style += "QListView::item:disabled { ";
    style += "color: blue;"; // Color works
    style += "font: bold italic large \"Times New Roman\";"; // Font doesn't work
    style += "}";

    v.setStyleSheet(style);

    v.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

As written in the comments, the height property works perfectly fine and the color property with a pseudo-state too.
But the font property does not work (with or without a pseudo-state) with the item sub-control.
(Example: I want to set a font property different to disabled items)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
   QString style = "";

   style += "QListView { ";
   style += "background: lightgrey;";
   // Font works here
   style += "font-family: Times New Roman;font-style: italic;font-size: 20pt;font-weight: bold;";
   style += "}";

   style += "QListView::item { ";
   style += "height: 40px;"; // Height works
   style += "}";

   style += "QListView::item:disabled { ";
   style += "color: blue;"; // Color works
   style += "}";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But if I want to set a different font property to disabled items, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't manage to find the answer how to do it with stylesheet. Looks like the default font in inherited from ListView and there is no way to specify it for children. I can be wrong.